# Adding an Image/blob to mysql database

Tags: mysql

This line of code says that it works (green check) but I don't see an image inserted. The file path should be correct because I got it from the file data.

```
 UPDATE `inventory`
SET bookImage = LOAD_FILE('C:\xampp\htdocs\1059\homework\books\wuthering.jpg')
WHERE isbn = '978-0141040356';
```

Comment: u are updating without any code?@Mei

Answer (score 0):

one thing u should have know that if you're connecting to a remote database server, the path is relative to the server that the DB is on, not your local machine.

```
UPDATE inventory
SET bookImage = 
(SELECT  BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK  N'C:\wuthering.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x)
WHERE isbn = '978-0141040356';
```